# Fortran runtime error while reading a file: "Bad repeat count"

Tags: file-io, fortran, complex-numbers

I'm trying to read an input file with fortran but I get the following error at runtime:

```
At line 118 of file prog.f90 (unit = 53, file = 'data.dat')
Fortran runtime error: Bad repeat count in item 1 of list input
```

The data file is the following

```
3, 5, 3 %comment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1d0, 0d0, 0d0 % comment
0d0, 0d0, 1d0 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1, 1, identity, 1, 1 %comment
1, 2, sigmax, 2, 2
2, 3, sigmax, 2, 2
1, 3, sigmaz, 1, 3
3, 3, identity, 1, 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
0, 0            %comment
```

and the interesting part of prog.f90 is

```
COMPLEX(KIND(1D0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE:: H1, H2
INTEGER :: i,A,B,C
CHARACTER(50) :: GHOST

OPEN(UNIT=53,file='data.dat',status='old')
READ(53,*) A,B,C
READ(53,*) GHOST
ALLOCATE (H1(A),H2(A))
READ(53,*) (H1(i), i=1,A)
READ(53,*) (H2(i), i=1,A)
```

where the 118th line is `READ(53,*) (H1(i), i=1,A)`. I tryed also with an explicit `do` loop but with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I'd expect

```
READ(53,*) (H1(i), i=1,A)
```

to try to read 3 complex numbers.  It gets fed the line

```
1d0, 0d0, 0d0 % comment
```

from which it gets 1½ complex numbers and then barfs on the `%` sign, misinterpreting it as a syntactically invalid repeat count.

I'd suggest providing 3 complex numbers in the file when that `read` statement is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are dimensioned complex, while in fortran complex numbers should be in the file with parenthesis as:
 ( realpart , imaginarypart )  ( realpart , imaginarypart )

I really don't know what the standards say regarding the input form you have presented, but after some testing `gfortran` throws that `Bad repeat count` error *regardless of the `% comment`*.  It throws that error even with four or more comma separated reals on the line.

Now `ifort` on the other hand reads the line just the way you have it -- but watch out -- it reads each of the comma separated values as the real part of your complex variable, setting the imaginary part to zero. ( that is it only uses the first two values on each line and discards the third )

You will really need to study the code to make sure you understand what was intended to sort out how to fix this.  If the later (`ifort`) behavior is the intention one simple fix would be to declare a couple of reals. Read into the reals, then assign those to your complex variables.